# Vuex access states in actions weird

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a Vuex store like this. When triggering the storeTest action from my component with `this.$store.dispatch("storeTest");` I need to use this weird syntax store.store to access an item.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    loading: false,
    fileStr: "data.json",
  },
  actions: {
    storeTest(state) {
     //works
      console.log("state: ", state.state.fileStr);
     //fail
      console.log("state: ", state.fileStr);
    },
    },
  },
});
```

I would expect I can access a state with state.item. Instead I have to write state.state.item. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because actions do not receive state as a parameter, but context. You need it to dispatch other actions or to commit.

```js
actions: {
  async myAction ({ state, dispatch, commit }) {
    console.log(state.loading);
    await dispatch('anotherAction')
    commit('someCommit')
  }
}
```

Full list of the context properties [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#actions).

Comment: ```  actions: {
    storeTest(context) {
      console.log("state: ", context.store.fileStr);
    },``` doesn't work

Comment: `context.state.fileStr` (instead of `store`) should work, except if you have a different issue.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to an action function is not `state`, rather `context` (see [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html)).

This "context" object has various properties, one of which is `state`.

This differs from a mutation where the first argument is `state`.

Comment: Using context.state.fileStr doesn't return the state either.

Comment: That contradicts the working statement you labelled in the question.

Answer (score 0):

refined and working thanks to @FitzFish

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    loading: false,
    fileStr: "data.json",
  },
  actions: {
    storeTest(context) {
     //works
      console.log("state: ", context.state.fileStr);
    },
  },
});
```